# Blazor - Multiples area - custom _Hostm.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, area

I have a blazor application with areas like this :

- Pages

  - _Host.cshtml
  - index.razor
- Area

  - products
  - Pages

    - _HostAdmin.cshtml
    - admin.razor

I need a custom _Host.cshtml for each area, with custom javascript, css etc...

I have try using multiples MapFallbackToPage and MapFallbackToAreaPage, but none work !
And I can't find such sample anywhere !

Any idea to solve this, I have a few questions:

1) Should I use MapFallbackToPage or MapFallbackToAreaPage and how ?
2) in _HostAdmin.cshtml should I have

PS: I have try to request MS help, but without a chance:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21574

Comment: In your project you have 2 different type of codes, 1: .cshtml , you can make use of nested layouts and in each layout you can reference the custom scripts and styles, 2: .razor files, you can use nested layouts but  unfortunately you can not reference scripts in .razor but consider that for .rzaor files you have only one  _Host.cshtml that is the root layout.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I only have one _Host.cshtml, I cannot have nested layouts inside _Host.cshtml, right ?

Comment: You can have nested layouts inside _Host.cshtml because it is a .cshtml file, for example you can create a layout tree _Host.cshtml(parent)  >  _Host1.cshtml(child1)  , _Host2.cshtml (child2)   then in you razor layout you can inherit from each of the .cshtml layouts that you want

Comment: Thanks, but how a .razor layout can inherit from _Host1.cshtml or _Host2.cstml ? The @layout directive request a class, not a cshtml !

Comment: In startup.cs we route to the desired .cshtml layout like this endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host2"); You can add other routes

Comment: Thanks Ali, but it is my question, I cannot find a way to route dynamically. When I have several _HostXXX.cshtml I got errors, and MapFallbackToPage with patterns does seems helpful ! I cannot make it work this way :-(

Comment: Ok, I make it work. Thanks. But now, when I navigate (button click by example) it keep the same layout. If I refresh, then it change the layout (use the right _HostXXX). Do you know why ?

Comment: Did you try StateHasChanged() while you navigate to a page with a different layout?

Comment: I can try, but when I navigate through the application, then anyway it will not refresh to the right _Host :-(

Answer (score 9):

Solution for file structure

- Pages

  - _Host.cshtml
  - index.razor
- Areas

  - Admin

    - Pages

      - _HostAdmin.cshtml
      - admin.razor

Page /admin/admin and /admin/admin/123 - other use default scheme

```
endpoints.MapControllers();
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
endpoints.MapFallbackToAreaPage("/Admin/admin", "/_HostAdmin", "Admin");
endpoints.MapFallbackToAreaPage("/Admin/admin/{Id:long}", "/_HostAdmin", "Admin");
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

or for all pages in /Admin/

```
endpoints.MapControllers();
endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
endpoints.MapFallbackToAreaPage("/Admin/{*clientroutes:nonfile}", "/_HostAdmin", "Admin");
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```

_hostAdmin.cshtml

```
@page "/admin/"
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_layoutAdministration";
}
<component type="typeof(AdminApp)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    <environment include="Staging,Production">
        An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
    </environment>
    <environment include="Development">
        An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
    </environment>
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: for more detail, plz see this example code: https://github.com/asabbah1/ASBlog/tree/8e6cf20c8d8327d162165a175f0d79d64174fb4f/ASBlog.Web